# How to replace Import-CSV to use a single command pipeline

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-iam

I have a powershell script that generates a report on AWS IAM users password and access key last usage.

My question is how to replace `Import-Csv` so that the intermediate CSV file is not created and a single pipeline is used.

My code:

```
$desiredColumns = 'user', 'arn', 'password_last_used', 'access_key_1_last_used_date', 'access_key_2_last_used_date'

# Request the creation of a credential report
Request-IAMCredentialReport

# Get the credential report and save as a CSV file
Get-IAMCredentialReport -AsTextArray > credential_report.csv

# Import the CSV file, select the desired columns and output as an HTML file
Import-Csv credential_report.csv | Select $desiredColumns | ConvertTo-Html > credential_report.html

# Launch the default web browser to view the credential report
start credential_report.html
```

[Upate after veefu's correct answer]

Here is the final code:

```
$desiredColumns = 'user', 'arn', 'password_last_used', 'access_key_1_last_used_date', 'access_key_2_last_used_date'

$reportFile = "credential_report.html"

# Request the creation of a credential report
Request-IAMCredentialReport

# Get the credential report and save as a variable
$data = Get-IAMCredentialReport -AsTextArray

# Process the variable, select the desired columns and output as an HTML file
$data | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select $desiredColumns | ConvertTo-Html > $reportFile

# Launch the default web browser to view the credential report
Invoke-Item $reportFile
```

Comment: `Get-IAMCredentialReport | Select $desiredColumns`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Thank you for responding. Yes, I tried that but the ConvertTo-Html cmdlet did not like the input. The answer from veefu works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try piping the output to `ConvertFrom-CSV`?

```
Get-IAMCredentialReport -AsTextArray |ConvertFrom-CSV | Select $desiredColumns | ConvertTo-Html > credential_report.html
```

Comment: Thank you. I could not remember the cmdlet to use. Your answer works perfectly. I updated my question with the final results.

Comment: Well, I'd forgotten it too. I ran a `get-command "*csv*"` to find it. Pretty handy when you're not *quite* sure if there's a cmdlet for something.